# Term for twisting, distorting, souring, tends to look for evil intent of others

Tags: single-word-requests

She has a tendency to take whatever a person says and (twists, sours, distorts, inflames as evil) to make some one look bad or way worse than they really are.

She would be having a conversation with another in a family setting. All the rest understands what the other is saying, but when "she" hears it, it is evident by her response that she was taking it as a negative about herself, or something she likes, which it was not.

Then she will single a phrase out from what was said and answer, obviously from a distorted perception, then embellish the distortion coming out with an inflamed, corrupted and evil twist, to sour everyone else's view of the person she is arguing with, to make herself seem good.

What would be a term to refer to such a way of communicating? Verb for the action, or adjective to describe it or term for such a Disorder?

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the single-word would fit? Are you looking for a noun, phrase or verb? In what context does she twist a story?

Comment: In this context is it to make something bad appear worse or something neutral/good look bad? If the former, **exacerbate** would do. 
_"She has a tendency to exacerbate a someone's misguided comments."_

Comment: This can only refer to current USA candidate politics, I'm sure.

Comment: "negatively [mis]interprete" ?

Comment: That's typically just called, "*twisting someones words around*"

Answer (score 3):

*twist* is probably the word you are looking for.

"If you give me six lines written by the hand of the most honest of men, I will find something in them which will hang him."
-- Cardinal Richelieu *(attrib.)*

Comment: Something that would add more evil, souring, distortion to the mere twist word.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the person is **[*exaggerating*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exaggerate)**

> Represent (something) as being larger, better, or worse than it really is

or if you are looking for a strictly negative word, then [***catastrophize***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catastrophize)

> View or present a situation as considerably worse than it actually is

[ODO]

Comment: Do we have enough context to answer the question? Is this question in line with our gudelines for single-word-request?

Comment: @Rathony - Nice point. I gave the benefit of the doubt to a new user. Of course, they can always edit their question to improve it so that it adheres to SWR tag requirements. Also, I have seen too many SWR questions without context or usage examples attracting answers from established users. So I don't think I am doing anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: The way I see the issue is this. Those SWR questions that attracted answers probably had some context. Then, it is okay not to have any example sentence. The question has neither context nor an example sentendce. Regardless of whatever happened before, we close the question first. If the Original Poster is desperate enought to get an answer, (s)he will edit the question. If not, we forget it. A user will take this question as an example that can be answered without any context or an example sentence in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Countless examples out there. To name a few, roughly in order of intensity:

[Defame](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defame)

> Damage the good reputation of (someone); slander or libel:
>   *'he claimed that the article defamed his family'*

[Discredit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discredit)

> Harm the good reputation of:
>   *'his remarks were taken out of context in an effort to discredit him'*

[Malign](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/malign)

> Speak about (someone) in a spitefully critical manner:
>   *'don’t you dare malign her in my presence'*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defame
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discredit
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/malign

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest ***impugn***:

> *to challenge as false (another's statements, motives, etc.); cast doubt upon*, from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impugn)

For example, *she **impugned** her brother's honour when she suggested he was a liar*

Answer (score 0):

**Falsify** can work

Falsify - to make false or incorrect, especially so as to deceive, as defined on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/falsify)